# HTML: Font-size 0 in TABLE

Tags: html, html-table, font-size

In a HTML-Table I have several columns, sortable by JavaScript. One column gets filled by numbers like 23, 61, 23 etc. and I would like to add some text after the numbers, which shall be used for sorting.
The numbers shall be visible <Font-Size=8> but the text behind shall have Size=0, in order not to increase the column with. My trials don't work, the text is still visible here:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
     <TITLE>sortable table</TITLE>
     <SCRIPT src="SortTable.js"></SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <TABLE CLASS=sortierbar BORDER=1 WIDTH=100% SOLID=1 STYLE='font-size:10pt; empty-cells:show;'>
        <THEAD>
            <TR>
                <TH CLASS=sortierbar WIDTH=8%>Idx - Id</TH>
                <TH CLASS=sortierbar WIDTH=3%>Grid</TH>
            </TR>
        </THEAD>
<TBODY>
    <TR>
        <TD>1 - 2630194544</TD>
        <TD>2015-01-01 2268 </TD>
        <TD>2021-02-25T18:26:05Z</TD>
        <TD STYLE=text-align:center>23<font size=0><I>Walter"</I></font></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>2 - 9570194548</TD>
        <TD>2015-01-01 2268 </TD> 
        <TD STYLE=text-align:center>62<font size=0><I>Peter</I></font></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>3 - 2630194548</TD> <TD>2015-01-01 2268 </TD> 
        <TD STYLE=text-align:center>23<font size=0><I>Susan</I></font></TD>
    </TR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Please format your markup properly. You can drop it into a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) and use the Tidy feature if you aren't using a good editor that does it.

Comment: The [font element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) is deprecated. You should be using CSS styles, but even then this isn't an accessible solution--screen readers will see your zero-size text. Use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead.

Comment: @isherwood — It *was* (literally) deprecated in 1998 and is now marked in the list of features that are ["entirely obsolete, and must not be used by authors"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features).

Comment: `<font size="0">` has *never* been valid. The smallest size allowed for it was `1`.

Comment: Thank you all and OK my approach is wrong. But what code would work to have the numbers visible and the text following size zero?

Comment: Use data attributes as previously mentioned.

Comment: I'm trying data attributes now: But no idea how to get it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my working solution: Created a new entry in the relevant CSS, there size=0 works:

```
H9
    { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    margin-top: 0pt;
    margin-bottom: 0pt;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #0F408D}
```